# How to merge all the elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a task to print out all the combinations of 'D' and 'E' in 4 character.
What i have:

```
x = product(['D', 'E'], repeat=4)
p = ''.join(str(s) for s in x)
lxx = []
lxx.append(p)
f = ''.join(lxx)
print(f)
```

What i get:

```
('D', 'D', 'D', 'D')('D', 'D', 'D', 'E')('D', 'D', 'E', 'D')('D', 'D', 'E', 'E')('D', 'E', 'D', 'D')('D', 'E', 'D', 'E')('D', 'E', 'E', 'D')('D', 'E', 'E', 'E')('E', 'D', 'D', 'D')('E', 'D', 'D', 'E')('E', 'D', 'E', 'D')('E', 'D', 'E', 'E')('E', 'E', 'D', 'D')('E', 'E', 'D', 'E')('E', 'E', 'E', 'D')('E', 'E', 'E', 'E')
```

What i need:

```
DDDD
DDDE
DDED
DDEE
DEDD
DEDE
DEED
DEEE
EDDD
EDDE
EDED
EDEE
EEDD
EEDE
EEED
EEEE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
from itertools import product

list(product(['D', 'E'], repeat=4))
```

For pretty printing:

```
for i in product(['D', 'E'], repeat=4):
    print(''.join(i))

# DDDD
# DDDE
# DDED
# DDEE
# DEDD
# DEDE
# DEED
# DEEE
# EDDD
# EDDE
# EDED
# EDEE
# EEDD
# EEDE
# EEED
# EEEE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
x = product(['D', 'E'], repeat=4)
for word in ["".join(x) for x in list(x)]: print(word)

DDDD
DDDE
DDED
DDEE
DEDD
DEDE
DEED
DEEE
EDDD
EDDE
EDED
EDEE
EEDD
EEDE
EEED
EEEE
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need something "less magical", I think you are looking for something like this:

```
def product(items, repeat, currentstring="", ret = None):
    if ret == None:
        ret = list()
    if len(currentstring) == repeat:
        ret.append(currentstring)
        print(currentstring)
    else:
        for letter in items:
            product(items, repeat, currentstring + letter, ret)
    return ret

product(['D', 'E'], repeat=4)
```

Other answers seems to work to. So, use this just in case you wanted to practice recursion or something. Good thing about it, is that is allows to receive more letters. Like, you could try

```
product(['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], repeat=4)
```